# How to explain the outcome?

Tags: sql, database, select, join

When i execute the SQL,why the result still contains isuser=1's data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys_userdept
LEFT JOIN sys_deptdef sys_deptdef ON sys_userdept.nodeid=sys_deptdef.deptid
AND isuser=0 ORDER BY sys_userdept.pnodeid,sys_userdept.relationid;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you use `LEFT JOIN` - it takes **all** records from first table, even when there is no matching record in joined one.

Move your `isuser=0` condition into `WHERE`:

```
select * 
from sys_userdept
left join sys_deptdef sys_deptdef on sys_userdept.nodeid=sys_deptdef.deptid
where isuser=0
order by sys_userdept.pnodeid,sys_userdept.relationid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've used a left join.

If you want the data for `isuser=1` then use an `INNER JOIN` or filter on a `WHERE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys_userdept
LEFT JOIN sys_deptdef sys_deptdef ON sys_userdept.nodeid=sys_deptdef.deptid
WHERE isuser = 0
ORDER BY sys_userdept.pnodeid,sys_userdept.relationid;
```

As an additional note, do not use `SELECT *`, explicitly state your columns.